# ¿como puedo iniciarlizar una matriz de caracteres en un constructor sin parámetros? C++

Tags: c++, matrices, class

Tengo una duda. como puedo inicializar una matriz de caracteres en el constructor de una clase.. se que las matrices de caracteres son como cadenas de caracteres y fácilmente podría trabajar con una de ella pero me han dejado un enunciado que me obliga a trabajar con matriz de caracteres.

bueno en si como yo he intentado hacer la inicializacion a la matriz de caracteres para que cada campo quede vasillo en el constructor haciendo: `nombrehuesped={"","","",""};` ya que en la clase donde declaro variables lo hago así `nombrehuesped[4][20]` para dejar espacio de 4 nombres de 20 caracteres. pero siempre en el compilador me da el siguiente error `parse error before ´{´ token`

y he tratado de hacerlo de otras maneras y no encuentro la correcta asi que me gustaría saber en que parte se encuentra mi error?

acá el código a que hago referencia: las librerias de la clase y la parte del problema principal de la inicializacion de matrices de caracteres.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#if !defined (_PARTICIPANTE_H_)

#define _PARTICIPANTE_H_

class CHotel
{
private:

    string nombrehotel;    //nombre del hotel
    int nhabitaciones; //nhabitaciones del hotel
    string direccion; //direccion 
    char nombrehuesped [4][20]; //matriz de caracteres esta comenta para que pueda compilar por el error de inicializacion

public:

    CHotel(); //constructor
    CHotel(int); //constructor con parametros
    ~CHotel(); //destructor 
    CHotel(const CHotel &); //constructor copia
    CHotel &operator=(const CHotel &); //sobrecarga
    void setnombre(string); //optienen el nombre del hotel
    void getnombre(string&)const; //devuelve el nombre del hotel
    void setdireccion(string); //optiene la direccion sin espacios
    void getdireccion(string&)const; //devuelve la direccion
    void reservacion(char, int[]); //hace reservacion (funcion de momento inutilizada)

};  

void GetDatos(const CHotel *,int); //devuelve todos lo datos

int Menu();

#endif
```

```
#include "participante.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

CHotel::CHotel(){

    nhabitaciones=0;
    nombrehotel="";
    direccion="";
    nombrehuesped={"", "","",""}; //aca esta el principar error 

}
```

gracias de manera anticipada.

Comment: Tene en cuenta que eliminar preguntas no hacen que desaparezcan del sistema. El sistema toma en cuenta todas tus preguntas, y puede decidir bloquearte si tus aportes negativos son mayores que positivos, y contra eso no podemos hacer nada. Dicho esto, evita poner una y otra vez la misma pregunta. Si no recuerdo mal, tenes que inicializar una por una cada posicion del array que llenar. Esto te lo van a poder confirmar algun experto en c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto, **dentro** del cuerpo del constructor, es una **asignación**:

```
nombrehuesped = { "", "","","" };
```

Y asignar valores a *formaciones* de esa forma **no está permitido**.

Otra cosa sería si lo estuvieramos *inicializando*, es decir, asignar valores **en el mismo punto en el que se declara la variable**. Eso si es perfectamente válido y permitido.

¿ Y como se inicializa **en un constructor** ? Pues simplemente, usando la *lista de inicialización*:

```
CHotel::CHotel( ) : nombrehuesped{ 0 } {
  nhabitaciones = 0;
  nombrehotel = "";
  direccion = "";
}
```

Ya puestos, pues lo podríamos hacer todo en la lista de inicialización:

```
CHotel::CHotel( ) :
  nombrehuesped{ 0 },
  nhabitaciones{ 0 },
  nombrehotel{ },
  direccion { }
{
}
```

Aunque, puesto que la inicialización mediante llaves en el constructor **solo es válida a partir de C++11**, podríamos aprovechar y utilizar la inicialización en el punto de declaración, lo cual hace mas fácil el mantenimiento del código:

```
class CHotel {
  int nhabitaciones = 0;
  char nombrehuesped[4][20] = { 0 };

  string nombrehotel;
  string direccion;

  ...
};
```

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que es un `string` la inicialización `nombrehotel{ 0 }` queda un poco rara, no crees?

Comment: @eferion inicializar un `std::string` con llaves no tiene nada de raro (desde C++11).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Es que había puesto `string{ 0 }` O_o Ya lo he cambiado

Comment: @Trauma ah, eso si que tiene algo de raro, más aún si teneos en cuenta que `std::string` lanza excepción al inicializarse con `0`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Que estaba inicializando `char[][]` ... y se me coló :-(

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no has leído el comentario completo :P

Answer (score 6):

Como complemento a la excelente (pero ligeramente incompleta) respuesta de [Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/262993/2742), me gustaría hablar de los tipos de inicialización de objetos de los que C++ dispone.

1. **Inicialización por defecto**: Dejará los sub-ojbetos del objeto con valores indeterminados.

   ```
   struct S { int valores[100]; };
   S s; // Inicialización por defecto.
   ```

   En el código anterior, `s.valores` tendrá valores indeterminados.
2. **Inicialización por valor**: Inicializará los sub-objetos según este criterio:

   1. Si el sub-objeto no dispone de constructor por defecto (autogenerado o proveído por el usuario) el sub-objeto se inicializará por defecto (valores indeterminados).
   2. Si el sub-objeto tiene constructor por defecto autogenerado o si se provee un constructor por defecto marcado como `default`, se aplicará inicialización a cero.

      ```
      struct S { int valores[100]; };
      S s{}; // Inicialización por valor.
      ```

      En el código anterior, `s.valores` se habrá inicializado a cero.
3. **Inicialización a cero**: Inicializará los sub-objetos según este criterio:

   1. Si el sub-objeto es un escalar, su valor será `0` convertido a su tipo.
   2. Si el sub-objeto es un objeto que no sea una unión, todos sus sub-objetos serán inicializados a cero. Los constructores, de haberlos, serán ignorados.
   3. Si el sub-objeto es una formación<sup>1</sup>, todos sus elementos se inicializan a cero.

      ```
      struct S { int valores[100]; };
      S s(); // Inicialización por valor, s.valores inicializado a cero
      ```

      En el código anterior, `s.valores` se habrá inicializado a cero.

#### Propuesta.

Aplicando estos conocimientos a tu código, podemos redactar la clase `CHotel` de la siguiente manera:

```
class CHotel
{
    string nombrehotel;
    int nhabitaciones;
    string direccion;
    char nombrehuesped [4][20];

public:
    CHotel() = default;
    CHotel(int);
    CHotel(const CHotel &);
    CHotel &operator=(const CHotel &);

    // ...
};
```

Los cambios que he hecho:

1. He eliminado `private:` del principio de la clase, en `class` todo es privado a no ser que se diga lo contrario.
2. He marcado el constructor por defecto como `default`, para poder usar la inicialización por valor.
3. He eliminado el destructor, no tienes nada en tu clase que requiera un tratamiento especial en el destructor, si lo quieres mantener puedes marcarlo como `default`: `~CHotel() = default;`

Con estos cambios, si inicializas una instancia de `CHotel` por valor, su matriz de caracteres se habrá inicializado a cero:

```
CHotel a{}; // a.nombrehuesped tendrá valores 0 en todos sus elementos.
```

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.